# Java: adding a new method to the interface List<E>

Tags: java, arraylist

Is there possible to add a new custom method to the well-known interface List in a way in Java? I tried to implement List interface to "public abstract class MyList", however, I would like to achieve it remaining the same name of the interface "List". For example, later implememnt in the following way:

```
List mylist = new ArrayList();
mylist.newmethod();
```

Comment: extend it `public interface YourList<E> extends java.util.List`

Comment: Imagine if this was possible. You could write this method: `public static void doStuff(List l) {l.newmethod();}`. Then someone else could write `doStuff(new ArrayList())`. What happens?

Comment: @immibis other languages (e.g. Objective C) support these types of extensions and avoid these problems. It can be very convenient.

Answer (score 6):

No, Java does not support such a feature. Use composition.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer! Could you give more details about what you mean "use composition"?

Comment: @DariusMiliauskas That's quite a big subject. [Here's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) the wiki article. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance) some justification.

Comment: @DariusMiliauskas you can google "object oriented composition" - you'll find tons of examples and explanations.

Comment: what is default keyword in Java 8? does it apply here?

Comment: @KickButtowski.  Yes.  Now run away fast.

Comment: FWIW, Java _deliberately_ omits this feature, considering it to be too easily abused.

Comment: @DavidWallace what u mean?

Comment: @DavidWallace: These are two different things.  Even in Java 8, you cannot add methods to interfaces you do not control.

Comment: Sure, sorry, I thought you meant something different @LouisWasserman

Answer (score 6):

You could extend it to another interface

```
interface MyList<E> extends List<E> {
    //add new methods here
}
```

Comment: The nice thing about this solution is that you can extend `List` implementations, and have them implement this.  So you can write something like `public class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> implements MyList<E>` and just write those methods in it that you've listed in `MyList`.

Comment: The disadvantage of this approach (as opposed to languages that allow extension) is that it doesn't then apply to all the classes that have already implemented List.

Comment: Haha, bring on Java 8's "default implementations".  @sprinter

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you want to do. I wouldn't recommend it though, it can be confusing to have two List classes.

```
public abstract class List implements java.util.List {
    public void myMethod() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: actually, I tried the same, but it requires to implement all other methods of java.util.List inside the abstract class.